# Is there a single word for "sunflower seeds"?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

I assume in many languages there are single terms to refer to "**sunflower seeds**", so I want to know if there is such a word in English also.

Example:
Tonight we should eat sunflower seeds while watching the movie.

Edit: I don't understand why this question is off-topic. Although there is no single word as answer, current answers explain the reason well.
I would expect that sunflower can imply "sunflower seeds" depend on the context and since we talk less about "sunflower plant".
This was not something I can find in the dictionary.

Comment: Do you refer to the translation in English of the spanish word "pipas" illustrated by this [image](http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iqrashop.com%2Fimages%2Fgraines-de-tournesol-pipas.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iqrashop.com%2FGraines-de-tournesol-grillees-Pipas-a-la-parrilla-alimentation-halal-Alimentation-Halal-p18699-39_234.html&h=409&w=700&tbnid=31seoWQDNEKQuM%3A&docid=c3bMWrQJdGt-TM&ei=F0AvVtOuC8yva-ahv2A&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=466&page=1&start=0&ndsp=31&ved=0CB4QrQMwAGoVChMIk5bH3afiyAIVzNcaCh3m0A8M) ?

Comment: @Graffito: Yes. I assume in many languages there are single terms to refer to "sunflower seeds", so I want to know if there is such a word in English also.

Comment: @Arman Could you please be a bit more specific about what kind of sunflower seed confectionery you're looking for? The candy bar one or the brittle style one?

Comment: @Elian: This is the picture of what I ment: http://www.iqrashop.com/images/graines-de-tournesol-pipas.jpg

Comment: @Arman I'm sorry, but this ain't confectionery. Confectionery are sweet foods.

Comment: @Elian, Thanks for notice. I am not English speaker and I didn't know that. Now I just edited the question.

Comment: @Arman I don't know of a single word, but how about "(dry) roasted sunflower seeds?"

Comment: I have next to me a bag of Gold Nut Roasted, Salted "Sunflower". The package does not say "seeds" though that's what is in it. In fact, the ingredients read, "Sunflower, Roasted Without Oil, Salt." It appears that the guy who wrote the label uses the single word "Sunflower" to mean "Sunflower seeds."

Comment: @Arman "sunflower kernel" is another term for "sunflower seed."  It's way less common, though. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sunflower+kernels%2Csunflower+seeds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csunflower%20kernels%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csunflower%20seeds%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Sunflower seeds* is just fine, why does it have to be "one word"? *Dried apricots* are two words, not one, is the English language any poorer for that? *Olive oil* two words, not one. The first word explains what type of seed, apricots and oil they are.

Comment: What are these single words in different languages that refer to "sunflower seeds"? If you could post a few of those, the question would, at least, be useful. http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=pipa *Pipa* Also called *pipa de girasol*

Comment: There is a single word in Turkish: *ayçekirdeği*. (literally *moonseed*) It is a compound noun.

Comment: You could have looked up the the term you use in your native language and translated that. Why don't you ask instead "why" there isn't a single word term in English? And are you really sure that Spanish has just the single-word term? It didn't look like that to me when I *searched* for its translation.

Comment: It's off topic because you didn't do the most basic of research, and you still haven't.

Comment: When i ask "is there" it means i am not sure about the results. So it was not possible to ask a "why not" question. My native language is not spanish. In my native language we can call this both (literal translation of) "seeds" or "sunflower". Yes in spanish they use a single word which is actually a brand name which produces sunflower seeds.

Comment: I hope you can be more specific about what you meant by most basic research. I have been using English as main communication language for the past 5 years. I was not translating from other language to English and i see no point in using bilingual dictionary.

Comment: You need to preface my username with @ otherwise I won't be notified. You are the OP of this post so I don't need to address you specifically. If someone want to know how something is called in a language that is not their mother tongue, the first thing they do is look up the word in a bilingual dictionary. *That* is what I meant by *basic* research, what answers did the dictionary provide? Why are you unconvinced? Explain. Give examples etc..  But if you find there's no point in using a dictionary, well there's not much I can do or say to persuade you otherwise.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: you can blame andriod app developers for not preaching your name. You mentioned that i need to use bilingual dictionary. The word we use is ver common in my langage but it's not in any official dictionary. When we say "the seed" it only refers to sunflower seed and that's it but there is no "the seed" entry in any dictionary. The reason i asked this question is to see if everyone calles this "sunflower seeds" or there are other terms that can be used (informally). Why should you make this question off-topic? That's what i don't know!

Comment: Your question is now being reviewed, if they agree with you, users will vote to reopen it. If they don't, I have explained it at least three times. If you want to act so stubborn and refuse to hear, I can't help you any further. But, let's remind ourselves. You have the answer, it's *sunflower seeds*, how many users can post this as an answer? Just the one.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that. And yes i have the answer which I wouldn't have if i wouldn't have asked. I just didn't like the question to have the "off-topic" label for no reason. And by the way, no one like having this boring debate for one question asked and i feel very sorry that I asked a question in this forum because it made me to have a long discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many plants lend their common English names to their constituent parts. "A **rose**" (by any other name), might refer to the entire plant, but it may also mean an individual bloom, perhaps on its stem. To clarify, you'd say something like "I bought a rose bush for the garden."

Some of these common names are widely understood to mean a *particular* part, **by default**, if not qualified in this way. This seems to be particularly true of *edible* parts.

"An **apple**", unless context suggests otherwise, means the *fruit* of the apple tree. To refer to the flower, you'd have to say *apple blossom*. Likewise, "a **carrot**" means the edible root part of that plant.
Peas, beans, potatoes, nuts etc. follow this pattern.

However, "a **sunflower**" would be understood by most to mean the distinctive flower itself. If you want to refer to the edible part of that plant (as commonly sold as a snack food), you need to qualify it: **"sunflower seeds"**.

This may be because the original main use of the plant in Western Europe was ornamental, rather than nutritional:

> This exotic North American plant was taken to Europe by Spanish explorers some time around 1500. The plant became widespread throughout present-day Western Europe mainly as an ornamental, but some medicinal uses were developed. By 1716, an English patent was granted for squeezing oil from sunflower seed.

(From the [National Sunflower Association](http://www.sunflowernsa.com/all-about/history/) website.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word for 'sunflower seed' in English. (this can really only be confirmed by comprehensive dictionary search, so I'm only using native speaker intuition).

This may be obvious to native English speakers because 'sunflower seed' seems to be sufficient. But it isn't totally unreasonable to expect one. There are often single words where a noun and modifier would be sufficient, for example, young female horse is a 'filly'. Or a nut from the hazel tree (a hazelnut is one word but that doesn't seem fair) is a filbert.

There'd surely be an explosion of vocabulary if every possible nut or seed had a different unique name for each species of seeded plant. So that English is missing one more than your language is no big loss.

Comment: I would have thought this was obvious to any person, regardless of what language they speak, it's just using common sense. The OP should have first checked in a bi-lingual dictionary. Why isn't the OP's question being closed? That's my question.

Comment: *sunflower seeds* takes three words to translate into Spanish, not one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA hm... yes, you're right, dictionary first. But no it's not obvious even for people who know more than one language. The drive for a single word is very strong however arbitrary its existence might be.